# "be across a problem"

Tags: prepositions, british-english, etymology, australian-english

The Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary labels the following sense of "across" British:

> (British English) knowing a lot about something; covering or in control of something
>
> *We need somebody who is across all the issues.*
>
> *Radio 8 will be across events as they unfold.*

But another Oxford dictionary says it's Australian.

Which label is right?

Comment: The usage is not familiar to me (as a BrE speaker).

Comment: @KateBunting - I have encountered it in UK business circles in recent years. I did not know its origin, but am willing to believe it came from Australia.

Comment: I believe it is an Australian phrase. Check the publishing dates of those dictionaries. One might include more recent corrections to previous editions' mistakes.

Comment: Even if evidence could be produced showing that the usage is or was more common among Australians, that wouldn't prove it *started* among Aussies. I don't see the point of this question, and I *certainly* don't believe it's possible to unambiguously identify an "origin" for such a trivial metaphoric extension (which will probably have been "re-coined" countless times all across the Anglophone world for centuries, without necessarily "sticking").

Comment: You don't see the point of this question because you don't know etymology is a legitimate topic on this site, as  its topic label exists here.

Comment: Which is the "other" Oxford dictionary you cite in your answer? And could you include the two links, please?

Comment: @Mari-LouA From The Oxford Dictionary of English (not the OED): be (or get) across something AUSTRALIAN fully understand all the details of an issue or situation.

Comment: @KateBunting The BBC says it **all the time**.